# Symbols for parts of a text?

Tags: print-design, symbols, paragraph, section-marker

Some texts may be divided into parts, chapters, sections and paragraphs. Sections are associated with the symbol $, and paragraphs with the [Pilcrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilcrow#:%7E:text=The%20pilcrow%2C%20%C2%B6%2C%20is%20a,used%20to%20identify%20a%20paragraph.).

My understanding is that there are no symbols associated with chapter.

Are there symbols which are associated with the parts of a document?

Comment: [Cross-site duplicate](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/20400/77065)

Comment: @ZachSaucier Not so: That question asks for a chapter symbol, whereas mine asks for a part symbol.

Comment: Are you asking about a certain kind of text, like a book, article, academic paper? All publishers have a style book that specifies this very thing. Some types of publishers have an in-house style book, many use commercially available style books like the Chicago Manual or Style. All may specify different symbols for the same situation.

Comment: Ah, my mistake.

Comment: @shashin-ka All sorts of text are of interest. Manuals of style, and their ilks, may be useful here. If not, there may be other sources, like histories of printing.

Comment: @Sapiens There is no universal set of symbols used to separate parts of printed tests. For example I have never seen "Sections are associated with the symbol $" in any text. Are you talking about marking up a manuscript for publication?

Comment: @shashin-ka I beg to differ:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilcrow
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_sign

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the question.....

- The Pilcrow ([¶](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilcrow)) designates paragraphs.
- [**§**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_sign) is a section symbol, similar to the pilcrow.
- According to [English.StackExchange.com](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20400/is-there-a-standard-symbol-for-denoting-a-chapter-in-a-citation) there's no universal symbol for chapters.

<sup>(English.se would probably be a better place to ask - since *that* is more likely where *writers* will be found -  but chances are it'll be a duplicate there.)</sup>

Beyond chapters, sections, and paragraphs - I don't know what other symbols one would expect. There are no symbols for a "word" or "sentence".

Front/back matter is usually designated by a change in page numbers, i.e. Roman numerals rather than Latin - or alpha glyphs rather than numerals. Footnotes are designated by size and placement.

However, you could try perusing some [standard punctuation lists](https://www.thesaurus.com/e/grammar/what-are-the-major-punctuation-marks/) to see if anything there is what you need.

Comment: "Beyond chapters, sections, and paragraphs - I don't know what other symbols one would expect." 

The question asked for a  p a r t  symbol.

Comment: @Sapiens **Part of what???** Part of a chapter? That's a section. Part of a section.. That's a paragraph. Part of a paragraph? That's a sentence. Part of a sentence? That's a word. You really aren't explaining yourself well. If you mean something like "text is continued elsewhere" then either "con't" or the standard ellipsis -- i.e. `...` As far as I'm aware, there's no symbol for "part" whatever you mean by that.

Comment: Books have parts, parts have chapters, chapters have sections, sections have paragraphs, paragraphs have definitions , lemmas, theorems, corollaries and other sentences. :)

Comment: Oh that's not a **design** question. You need to ask at English.SE. The **type** of sentence is not something *designers* care about. If you want symbology which *describes* the text broken down to it's subject, verb, adverb, adjectives, etc...... you're not asking a **design** question. (and no, as far as I'm aware, nouns, verbs, etc, have no symbol other than what a dictionary may use, i.e. *n* or *v*.)

Comment: Thanks. I am also not interested in the type of sentence. 

I am however, preoccupied with design. 

If I write a theorem, I use \begin{theorem} Some theorem text. \end{Theorem}, and similarly for lemmas, definitions, and so on. That's OK.

Occasionally, I have used the Pilcrow paragraph sign, and the Section sign $. But I may well kick that habit, instead of inventing chapter and part symbols.

Comment: Well theorem, lemmas, etc. **are** *types* of sentences. They are descriptors. Example: The Pilcrow designates a paragraph. It doesn't designate *only* paragraphs which are not inquisitive in nature (questions). *All* paragraphs, regardless of the overall context, can be noted by the Pilcrow.

Comment: Yes, corollaries, and so on, are of course sentences. As an apropos to your note on Pilcrows.: Do you agree that the section sign $ can be used for sections, subsection and so on?

Comment: Yes in general but $ is a dollar sign, it's not the same as § `:)` I would tend to use §§ for subsections.

Comment: :) I use §§ for sections, so e.g. §§6-10, or §§6 and 10. I only use § and §§ when referring to the sections, and not in the left margin before the section number.